# Ionic - Problema em carregar GoogleMaps no emulador e dispositivo móvel

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

No browser o googlemaps carrega normalmente, já em um emulador ou celular o aplicativo abre mas fica tudo em branco como na foto, já instalei as dependencias googlemaps, geolocation e network.

[image: Aplicativo executado pelo emulador]

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado no console?

Comment: não aparece erro algum no console

Comment: Você ta usando o chrome pra olhar o console, certo?

Comment: sim, no chrome roda normal, somente no emulador que da esse problema

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu, tente inspecionar o emulador pelo chrome:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257350/como-verificar-o-console-de-um-aplicativo-ionic-rodando-no-smartphone/257359#257359

Comment: Sei que a questão é antiga, mas descobriu o problema? No meu caso aparece só o logotipo do google, tanto no Android quanto no iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Quando a página fica em branco é que há algum erro. Checa o console do Chrome ([Como abrir o console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=pt-br)).
É bem estranho você conseguir executar no Navegador e não no Emulador/Celular. Qual o comando que você tá usando?

```
ionic run android
```

Para testar no celular (deve estar plugado no USB) utilize:

```
ionic run android --device
```

Comment: eu usei esses comandos mesmo, porém quando abre, abre em branco sem erro no console