# Como verificar o console de um aplicativo ionic rodando no smartphone

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Como posso abrir o console de uma aplicação rodando em um dispositivo? Gostaria de analisar os logs que coloquei no aplicativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível utilizar o Chrome pra analisar o console, debugar a aplicação e outros recursos.

Se preferir utilizar um dispositivo físico em vez de um emulador e necessário habilitar o [modo de desenvolvedor](https://mecanicadoandroid.com/como-ativar-e-desativar-modo-desenvolvedor-no-android/) do mesmo e ativar a depuração USB.

Abra o **Google Chrome** e na barra de endereços digite o seguinte caminho:

```
chrome://inspect
```

Em seguida uma página semelhante a essa será exibida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa página em baixo do título **Remote Target** todos os dispositivos que estão conectados ao PC serão exibidos, no meu caso estou usando um emulador. Para conseguir visualizar o console e inspecionar o app é só clicar em `inspect` e uma nova página abrirá, a mesma irá exibir o app de forma "espelhada" e nessa página podemos ter acesos ao console e aos outros recursos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]